# Calculating Volatility

Tags: excel, vba, finance

I have a question regarding volatility calculation in Excel.
My Table consists out of three columns: One identifier (Column A) one Date (Column B) and the value I want to calculate the Volatility for (Column C). The Identifier is listed more than once, so it's not unique in the table.

Now I want to create another table. IN Column A are the Identifiers of the first table, but they are unique now. In Column b (Where the problem is Located) i want to calculate the volatility of each value of the first table, where the Identifier equals the now unique Identifier in table 2.
At best if it is just a VBA written Workbook Function.
--> It should function similar to a "Group by" in SQL bout also calculates the volatility.

[image]

Thanks for your help in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to group values in Excel is by using the `Group` function:

[image]

Once they're grouped, you can calculate volatility with `DEV.ST` / `AVERAGE` by:

- Using **Excel Formula** `=DEV.ST(Range) / AVERAGE(Range)`
- Using **VBA Code** using `Application.WorksheetFunction` methods.

If you chose the **VBA way**, you can something like this:

```
Range("Result").VALUE = Application.WorksheetFunction.StDev(Range("YourData")) _
    / Application.WorksheetFunction.Average(Range("YourData"))
```